# Knockout JS mapping link returning DOCTYPE syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, doctype

I'm trying to use the Knockout JS mappping plugin from Steve Sanderson to bind an object I'm getting from a .NET controller POST method.

I downloaded [this file](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output) to my "Scripts" folder and included it in my project as Content.  I added the following link to my view (below the jquery link and knockout link - all of which are working).

My link looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

However, I keep getting a "Syntax Error" on the DOCTYPE html in Firebug.

When I remove the link, the error goes away.  When  i re-add the link, the error returns.  Inside of Firebug I'm able to hit the "plus" sign next to the script tag, and it displays the source code, which I'm thinking means it can find the file.

I've used the exact same syntax with other js files in the "Scripts" folder and they work fine.

The only thing I can think of is there is some kind of error within the file itself that is causing this problem.

Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Comment: If it couldn't find the file it wouldn't be able to display the source code. Is it the source code? Or a stack/function trace? You don't need the type attribute on script elements anymore either

Comment: Double-check the name that the file to make sure it's correct (check the network traffic in Firebug or just type the path of the script into the location bar of the browser). Looks like the server is not returning the file and returning some error HTML page instead (404?).

Comment: You could try creating a new file and copy and paste the mapping contents into it.